# Is "so" omissible in "so their makers claim"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, parts-of-speech

> "The Painting Fool" is one of a growing number of computer programs which, so their makers claim, possess creative talents"

Is "so" omissable in this context? If not, what role does it play in this sentence, and what does it mean? Side question: Can "so" be replaced by "as", and if so, is "as" also omissable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this sentence "so" expresses scepticism. Omitting it would make this a simple statement that the makers make this claim. With "so" there is a definite implication that writer isn't totally convinced their claims are true. "as" could repace "so" but would have a positive connotation. It would endorse the makers claim but, again, in a subtle way.